# Regarding Facebook fbq('track', 'Lead'); - is there a way to track different kind of leads?

Tags: facebook, lead, facebook-pixel

in example - 
I have a webpage with 2 buttons - 
1. Call
2. SMS

I want to  separate Leads for that (let's call it Lead_call and Lead_sms), since I want to run campaigns that focus optimisation per action (1 for Lead_call and 1 for Lead_sms).

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.8#standardevents

Answer (score 4):

That's possible by specifying additional variables for each lead.

Check this help article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/events-advanced-use-cases/v2.9

```
<!-- Facebook Event Code -->
<script>
    fbq('track', 'Lead', {
        content_name: 'booking',
        content_category: 'voucher',
        value: 1.00,
        currency: 'EUR'
    });
</script>
```

In this example the event `Lead` is specified with `content_name` and `content_category`. These additional variables are later accessible to distinguish between different Lead types.

Comment: Here it defines the property for each event. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/meta-pixel/reference